# UNIX: Move files from subfolders to another folder

Tags: unix

I have a directory containing folders and subfolders. These subfolders contain, for example, `.xml` files.

I'd like to copy all of the `.xml` files into a separate folder. My UNIX is rusty; any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command (with the needed changes of course), e.g.,:

```
cp source_dir/project1/*.xml dest_dir/new_project2/summer2012
```

Note that you don't have to specify the filenames at the destination when they stay the same.

For more information see the [cp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp)

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean copy all .xml files from all subfolders without having to specify the subfolder names?

```
find . -name \*.xml -exec /bin/cp {} /dest/dir/ \;
```

Comment: A variation of this worked for me to copy several thousand files from 40ish subdirs to one single directory: `$ find . -exec cp {} /target/dir \;`

Answer (score 2):

```
find -iname '*.xml' -exec mv \{\} /dest/directory \;
```